# Correct use of Transfixed

Tags: grammaticality

Which of these is the correct use of transfixed ?

- He moved ahead, his eyes transfixed **to** the sword.
- He moved ahead, his eyes transfixed **by** the sword.
- He moved ahead, his eyes transfixed **at** the sword.
- He moved ahead, his eyes transfixed **on** the sword.

They all sound proper to me but which of the above is grammatically accurate ?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfix) says you should use "by", which agrees with my sensibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sentence were

> He moved ahead, transfixed ___ the sword.

By far the most common usage would be *by* (see [Ngram here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transfixed%20by%2Ctransfixed%20on%2Ctransfixed%20at%2Ctransfixed%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctransfixed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctransfixed%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctransfixed%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctransfixed%20to%3B%2Cc0)). This makes sense with the basic definition of [*transfix*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transfix). From Oxford Dictionaries (as are all definitions in this answer):

> **VERB** *[WITH OBJECT]*
>   1. Cause (someone) to become motionless with horror, wonder, or astonishment.

We most often use *by* with transfix because the transfixing thing (in this case, the sword) is *causing* the transfixion; [*by*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by), of course, is a preposition

> 1. Identifying the agent performing an action.

In your actual sentence, however, "he" is not transfixed, his *eyes* are. In this case, it seems a bit odd to have the sword be the causative actor, as if the eyes themselves have volition to be fascinated or horrified. The word *transfixed* here is being used more as a substitute for words like *fixed* or *trained*, with the implication being that the reason for the unwavering gaze is their owner's transfixion.

With phrases like *his eyes were **fixed*** and *his eyes were **trained*** we would usually expect the preposition [*on*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on), in the sense

> 5. Having (the thing mentioned [in this case the sword]) as a target, aim, or focus.

And in fact, in this extended usage of *transfixed* this seems to be the most common collocation:

[image: Google Ngram of "eyes transfixed" with *by*, *on*, *at*, and *to*, showing *on* as the most common collocation, followed by *by* and a few instances of *to*]
([Source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eyes%20transfixed%20by%2Ceyes%20transfixed%20on%2Ceyes%20transfixed%20at%2Ceyes%20transfixed%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceyes%20transfixed%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceyes%20transfixed%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceyes%20transfixed%20to%3B%2Cc0))

So for your actual sentence, I would suggest

> He moved ahead, his eyes transfixed **on** the sword.

Comment: your accompanying explaination really makes it clear...amazing answer...Thanks